# pam_umask.so doesn't work

Tags: linux, centos, security, pam, umask

I try to configure pam.d on a centos 8.
I wanted to configure system wide umask to 0077 in `/etc/pam.d/postlogin`.

`postlogin` is included by several services under `/etc/pam.d` e.g. su, su-l

My `postlogin` looks like

```
session optional                   pam_umask.so umask=0077
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service !~ gdm* service !~ su* quiet
session [default=1]                pam_lastlog.so nowtmp showfailed
session optional                   pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate showfailed
```

I have tried to login with `su -l username` aswell as `su username` and calling umask both will have a umask of 0022.

I have to mention, that the umask is also set in `/etc/profile` for all accounts to 022.

I also tried to increase `pam_umask.so` verbosity with `debug` and consulted the logs `/var/log/{messages,secure,audit}` there are no entries which explains why `pam_umask.so` is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to mention, that the umask is also set in /etc/profile for all accounts to 022.

Every shell that uses /etc/profile will override the umask set by `pam_umask.so`. So you should set the umask in /etc/profile also to 0077 if you want a system wide umask.